# How to wait to finish loading page on button click using JavaScript/JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, page-refresh

I am having an Anchor link, on click of Anchor link, I am registering new JavaScript file html page.

On registering the JavaScript file dynamically, document is reloaded partially (As I see reload icon in browser for some time).

I want to call my JavaScript function once the script got registered (Obviously when reload icon get stopped in the browser). But the function `MyJavaScriptFunction` got called while document is still reloading.

Using `setTimeOut` resolves the issue but I don't want to use it as page loading time is not fixed. Please help.

The code I am using is as follow:

```
function addScriptDynamically(src, callback) {
    var s = document.createElement('script');
        s.setAttribute('src', src);
        s.onload = callback;
        document.body.appendChild(s);
}

addScriptDynamically('URL Of JS File',function(){

    MyJavaScriptFunction();
})
```

What I tried so far...

**Option-1:**

```
addScriptDynamically('URL Of JS File',function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        MyJavaScriptFunction();
    });
})
```

**Option-2:**

```
addScriptDynamically('URL Of JS File',function(){
    $(window).load(function(){
        MyJavaScriptFunction();
    });
})
```

Comment: removing jquery tag as title says Javascript

Comment: `What I tried so far...` anything not working with these methods - error messages in the **developer** tools console for example

Comment: are you sure it's head ? document.body

Comment: adding file to head or body will not make any difference. Still I removed the confusion

Comment: personally, I would wrap the **call to** addScriptDynamically in `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: I am calling `addScriptDynamically` on click of anchor link

Comment: not in that code in the question you aren't - and if you are, then there's no need to wait for document ready, because you won't be able to click until the document is ready

Comment: you are loading jQuery, of course?

Comment: No, loading some other javascript api. Let me update question to include more details. I guess its still creating consusion.

Answer (score 4):

jquery has a function for this purpose.

**Using jquery**

```
$(function () {
 //write your function code here.
})
```

This function is called only when the content of the page are first loaded.

2)
**Using Javascript**

```
window.onload = function(){
 //write your function code here.
}
```